# Calculator closing just as answer is given

Tags: java, batch-file, calculator

I made a circle area calculator. It's my first program and I am trying to make it run off of a .bat. The .bat has the command "java -jar CircleAreaApp.jar" in it. When I use it off the cmd, it works fine. But when I use it from a .bat, it closes just after you enter the radius and shows the answer. Is there a way to keep it open and/or copy the output to a document like a .text?

Comment: pull up some code and describe it further. So people could understand it what are you actually trying to ask.

And output can be directly be put up into a text file.

Comment: Add a 'pause' command after calling your program.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a [Pause](http://ss64.com/nt/pause.html) at the end of the bat file

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pause` as others have suggested, or you switch to a Java Swing approach, or you could prompt for user input (and wait) like this -

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please press enter to close");
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  scanner.nextLine();
}
scanner.close();
```

Comment: 1. You don't need the `scanner.hasNextLine()` part 2. How is this a "Java Swing approach"?

Comment: 1. What about Ctrl-D? 2. There was the ", or" between Swing and prompt for user input.